# Online Algorithms books

Tags: reference-request, big-list, online-algorithms

Are there any recent books on Online Algorithms? I know of only two books on the subject.

- Online Computation and Competitive Analysis by Allan Borodin and Ran El-Yaniv: This is a classic but old book, and does not contain many recent advances in the field.
- [The Design of Competitive Online Algorithms via a Primal-Dual Approach](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nivb/download/pd-survey.pdf) by Niv Buchbinder and Joseph (Seffi) Naor: This is a new book and contains lot of recent results. However, it's scope is limited to LP based primal-dual algorithms.

Please list here all the books on Online Algorithms that you may know. If there are any books freely available on the web, that will be great.

Comment: Sounds like a CW questions ? definitely a big-list

Comment: have noticed on tcs.se over ~1yr a seeming uptick in interest in online algorithms for eg misc std graph problems, seems to tie in with trends around "big data" (& cloud algorithms etc). & it would seem there are not great refs on the subj so far, the coverage seems more scattered right now... in many cases taking efficient offline algorithms & making/adapting them to online scenarios is an extremely nontrivial/advanced area... maybe early signs of a paradigm shift in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are no recent books or survey papers on online algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some relevance
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~arielpro/15896s15/docs/paper13b.pdf
Survey by Aranyak Mehta (Google Research)

Comment: Title for the lazy: "Online Matching and Ad Allocation"